# JSON format values get separately using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is JSON format.

```
[  
  {  
    user_id:"UID20",
    first_name:"Vasanthis",
    email:"vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com"
  },
  {  
    user_id:"UID19",
    first_name:"Murali",
    email:"murali.m@redbeaninc.com"
  }
]
```

I need to get email id alone. How can I get this above JSON format using node js?

I tried below methods. But it is not working:

```
var jsonData2 = 
[{user_id:"UID20",first_name:"Vasanthis",email:"vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com"},
{user_id:"UID19",first_name:"Murali",email:"murali.m@redbeaninc.com"}];

   var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData2));
    for(var k=0; k < jsonData[0].email.length; k++){
           var t1 =jsonData[k];
           console.log(t1.email);
      }
```

Comment: what do you mean *get email id alone*? Post what output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this code

```
var jsonData2 = 
[{user_id:"UID20",first_name:"Vasanthis",email:"vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com"},
{user_id:"UID19",first_name:"Murali",email:"murali.m@redbeaninc.com"}];

for(var k=0; k < jsonData2.length; k++){
   var t1 =jsonData2[k];
   console.log(t1.email); 
}
```

Comment: please define your problem more than that, it works like a charm for me.
Here is a link for a screen shot https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o6y2ZqDQWkipw7oplsSH3eGdxsdY6Cc-

Answer (score 0):

try below , you are doing wrong with length , you have to count the length of the array.

```
for(var k=0; k < jsonData.length; k++){
           console.log(jsonData[k].email);
      }
```

Comment: You don't need `t1` either

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i already tried your code. It's displaying undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in loop is incorrect it is not pointing to the array length.Use **jsonData.length** instead in the loop.

```
var jsonData2 = [{user_id:"UID20",first_name:"Vasanthis",email:"vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com"},{user_id:"UID19",first_name:"Murali",email:"murali.m@redbeaninc.com"}];
var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData2));
 for(var k=0; k < jsonData.length; k++){
           var t1 =jsonData[k];
           console.log(t1.email);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an array of email seperately, use `map`

```js
var jsonData2 = [{
  user_id: "UID20",
  first_name: "Vasanthis",
  email: "vasanthi.g@redbeaninc.com"
 },
 {
  user_id: "UID19",
  first_name: "Murali",
  email: "murali.m@redbeaninc.com"
 }
];
const jsonData = jsonData2.map(x => x.email);
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: jsonData2.map is not a function error showing in your code.

Comment: It's working here, try clicking the `Run code snippet` button

Comment: Yes its working here. If i add in my node js code, it display this error 'jsonData.map is not a function'. Do you know why this error coming this place?